# Problems installing mysql 5.5 on mac using cmake

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cmake

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails, and it looks like I'll need some type of database to build a basic web application according to the tutorials. So I'm trying to download and install MySQL onto my Mac according to [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installing-source-distribution.html). However, I'm running into a variety of problems. Unix isn't recognizing the following commands:

```
groupadd mysql
useradd -g mysql mysql
```

I tried `addgroup` and `adduser` but I also get a `command not found` error.

So then I tried to go ahead and configure mysql using cmake with the following commands:

```
cd mysql-5.5.12
cmake .
```

But I get `command not found` for cmake as well. I installed CMake and put it in my Applications directory, but is there something else I need to do to be able to access it from the command line?

In general, is there a simpler way to install mysql just for the purpose of working in RoR? Or is there a different database? I'm using [this tutorial](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails-revisited.html?page=2), which assumes "the MySQL engine is running."

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a couple good solutions for this.

1) Install homebrew - https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew - then run "brew install mysql"

2) Install macports - http://macports.org - then run "sudo port install mysql5-server-devel"

There are benefits to both package managers, however either will work for your usage case. If you want the absolute latest version of mysql you can get it at my custom macports repo at http://github.com/zquestz/ports

I also happen to have percona server builds there as well, but that is definitely optional.

If you google for "macports mysql" or "homebrew mysql" there are tons of online tutorials.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has downloads for OSX 10.5 and 10.6 here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads

CMake should work just fine on Mac, as it did for me (I do not own a Mac since couple of month, but I do not recall any problems using it previously. I used to use dmg installer from here http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html )